# I have a class emp with id name and list of technology type i want to fill it with data coming from dynamic textboxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

**i want it to be solved in only angular-js.**

```
    <head>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AddEmployee")
    </head>

    <body ng-app="TruModule">
        <div ng-controller="trucontrolleraddemp">
            <div style="margin-top:-20px;">
                <h1 class="decor">Add Employee</h1>

                <form name="emp" novalidate class="warn container" ng-mouseover="hidemessage()">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <table class="margin">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="id">Id*&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;:</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>{{id}}</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="name">Name*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="employee.name" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" />
                                        <span ng-show="emp.name.$touched && emp.name.$error.minlength">too short!!!</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="role">Role&emsp;&emsp;:</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="role" ng-model="employee.role" ng-maxlength="3" />
                                        <span ng-show="emp.role.$touched && emp.role.$error.maxlength">exceed!!!</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    @* <td>
                                        <label for="role">tech&emsp;&emsp;:</label>
                                    </td>
                                   <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="role" ng-model="technology.tech" ng-maxlength="6" />
                                        <span ng-show="emp.role.$touched && emp.role.$error.maxlength">exceed!!!</span>
                                    </td>*@
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <table id="tblEmployee">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="tech">Technologies*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li ng-repeat="techno in technology track by $index">

                                                <input  type="text" name="tech" ng-model="employee.technology[$index].tech" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span><button class="img" ng-click="addtech()">+</button></span><br/><span><button class="img" ng-click="removetech()">-</button></span>
                                    </td>       
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="mainloc">
                    <span><a class="img" href="#!Employee">&lt</a><button class="img position" ng-click="postdata(employee)" value="Submit">+</button> </span>
                </div>
                <span class="position" ng-hide="IsShown">
                    <img src="~/reload.gif" />
                </span><span style="visibility:hidden"><img src="~/reload.gif" /></span>
            <div class="dex alertpos" ng-hide="IsVisible">{{message}}</div>
           </div>

            <hr style="margin-top:91px;" />

        </div>
    </body>
```

i want data to be in the following format. it is the format
accepted by the model employee in controller in webapi.

```
       {
        "id":1,
        "name":"erk",
         "role": "sa",
         "technologies":[
          {"tech":"Test3"},
          {"tech":"Test1"},      
         ]
        },
      }          

the format i am getting is like 
this


     {"id":4,
    "name":"Sam",
    "role":"sa",
    "technology
        ":{"0":{"tech":"dfg"},
          "1": {"tech":"dfgdfg"}},
          }
```

I have tried using [$index] to make sure that each text box gets a 
different value. But since it is returning objects with indexes, I do not 
want like that. I want it to be replaced with tech.

```
     /// <reference path="../scripts/angular-route.min.js" />
    /// <reference path="../scripts/angular.min.js" />
   /// <reference path="../scripts/angular-route.js" />




       trumodule.service("idgenerator", function () {
        this.idfunc = function () {
            return Math.floor(((Math.random()) * 6) + 1);
        }
    });

    var trucontrolleraddemp = function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $route, idgenerator) {
        var id = idgenerator.idfunc();
        $scope.id = id;
        $scope.IsShown = true;
        $scope.technology = [];
        $scope.addtech = function () {
            $scope.technology.push({});
        }
        $scope.removetech = function () {
            $scope.technology.pop({});
        }
        $scope.postdata = function (data) {
            if (data)
                $scope.IsShown = false;       
            data.id = id
            var employee = JSON.stringify(data);
            $http({ method: "Post", url: '/api/values', data: employee, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.IsVisible = false;
                    $scope.message = response.data;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $route.reload();
                    }, 2000);

                });
        }
        $scope.message = "Please fill the fields to register a new Employee";
        $scope.hidemessage = function () {
            $scope.IsVisible = true;
        }
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.message = "Its mandatory to fill fields with *";
        }, 2000);

    }


    trumodule.controller("trucontrolleraddemp", trucontrolleraddemp);
```

I have a class employee in that i have fields id, name, role and a list 
technologies of type technology, which is another class containing string 
field tech, I want data to be filled in that using ng-repeat.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAPI_Angular.Models
{
       public class Employee
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string role;
        //public DateTime DoB;
        public List<technology> technologies;
    }

    public class technology
    {
        public string tech;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to get the dynamic text boxes to render or are you trying to get it to be accepted by the Web API controller? You seem on the right path except where you binding the ng-model to 0 instead of an index.

Comment: You should post the angularjs code as well then

Comment: The data format that you want is illegal syntax.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: When compiling it --  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `:`

Comment: hi georgeawg thanks for the notice. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative answer for my question but really want someone to tell me how can i bring the data at once and that too in the accepted format. Here i am posting my answer.

```
var trucontrolleraddemp = function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $route, idgenerator) {
    var id = idgenerator.idfunc();
    $scope.id = id;
    $scope.IsShown = true;
    $scope.technologies = [];
    $scope.addtech = function () {
        $scope.minus = true;
        if ($scope.technologies.length<3)
        $scope.technologies.push({});
    }
    $scope.removetech = function () {
        $scope.technologies.pop({});
        if (!$scope.technologies.length)
            $scope.minus = false;
    }
    $scope.postdata = function (employee, technologies) {
        if (employee)
    $scope.IsShown = false;
        employee.id = id
    $scope.employee.technologies = [];
        angular.forEach(technologies, function (value) {
           $scope.employee.technologies.push(value);
        });
        var employee = JSON.stringify(employee);
    $http({ method: "Post", url: '/api/values', data: employee, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.IsVisible = false;
                $scope.message = response.data;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $route.reload();
                }, 2000);

            });
    }
    $scope.message = "Please fill the fields to register a new Employee";
    $scope.hidemessage = function () {
        $scope.IsVisible = true;
    }
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.message = "Its mandatory to fill fields with *";
    }, 2000);

}


trumodule.controller("trucontrolleraddemp", trucontrolleraddemp);
```

I am posting only changes that i have done in html.

```
<td>
                                        <label for="tech">Technologies*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li ng-repeat="techno in technology track by $index">

                                                <input  type="text" name="tech" ng-model="employee.technology[$index].tech" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span><span><button class="img2" ng-click="addtech()">+</button></span><span class="mar-l20"><button class="img2" ng-show=minus ng-click="removetech()">-</button></span></span>
                                </td>       
                            </tr>
                            </table>
```